# What is the best package/algorithm to solve a large optimization problem in R?

Tags: r, optimization

The problem has an exponential objective and exponential equality constraint function.Both my objective and constraint function are differentiable.

I would want to solve it using lagrange method and also want the function to output lagrange multiplier. I am currently exploring aug_lag in nloptr and solnp in rsolnp.

**First question:**
Would you suggest these packages or i should explore any other package?

**Second question:**
I know that rsolnp and nloptr performs local optimisation majorly but if i want to do global optimisation on a similar problem, can you suggest any package / algorithm?

Comment: Questions which elicit opinion based answers are regarded as off topic.

Comment: Typically you cannot find proven global solutions for large problems. Good results may be obtained by multi-start approaches using local NLP solvers. Large NLP problems typically require sparse NLP solvers. The solvers you mention are for small, dense problems. Global solutions for smaller problems can be obtained using global solvers.